# recreate() increasing memory footprint

Tags: android, android-activity, memory-leaks, locale

I have an activity with two radio buttons with titles: `Hindi` and `English`.

In order to refresh UI, as per language selected by user, I am performing below steps:

1. Updating user preferences with language code
2. Invoking `recreate()` method
3. In `onCreate()` obtaining language code from preferences
4. Based on obtained language code updating the locale
5. Finally setting ContentView

Problem is -

> when I am continuously toggling between the two languages it is
>   linearly increasing memory footprint of the app as observed in
>   'Android Monitor'.

Below is the code:

```
//region Activity Life Cycle methods
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        refreshLocaleAsPerPreferences();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
        markRadioButtonSelectedAsPerPreferences();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        previousLanguage = null;
    }

    //endregion

    //region Locale refresh related methods
    private void updateLocale(String languageIsoCode) {
        if(languageIsoCode != null && languageIsoCode.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
            return;
        }
        Locale locale = new Locale(languageIsoCode);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        getResources().updateConfiguration(config,getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }

    private void refreshLocaleAsPerPreferences() {
        // Obtaining language from shared preferences
        String languageIsoCode = getLangFromPreferences();

        // Check for null
        if(languageIsoCode != null && languageIsoCode.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
            // No language found
            // Obtaining language from device preferences
            String devicePreferencesLanguage = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
            if (devicePreferencesLanguage.equalsIgnoreCase(HindiISOCode)
                    || devicePreferencesLanguage.equalsIgnoreCase(EnglishISOCode)) {
                // Device preferences language is one of the default languages
                // Hence update the same
                languageIsoCode = devicePreferencesLanguage;
            }
            else {
                // Device language is different than the default languages
                // Hence default to english
                languageIsoCode = EnglishISOCode;
            }

            // update language in preferences
            updateLangIsoCodeInPreferences(languageIsoCode);
        }

        // Updating locale
        updateLocale(languageIsoCode);
        previousLanguage = languageIsoCode;
    }
    //endregion

    //region radio button selection related methods
    private  void markRadioButtonSelectedAsPerPreferences() {
        String languageInPreferences = getLangFromPreferences();
        markRadioButtonSelected(languageInPreferences);
    }

    private  void markRadioButtonSelected(String languageCode) {
        RadioButton radioButton = getRadioButton(languageCode);
        radioButton.setChecked(true);
    }

    private RadioButton getRadioButton(String tag) {
        switch (tag) {
            case HindiISOCode: return (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio_hindi);
            case EnglishISOCode : return (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio_english);
            default:
                // if any other language is selected
                // select english
                return (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio_english);
        }
    }

    private void refreshUI(String lang) {
        updateLangIsoCodeInPreferences(lang);
        recreate();
    }
    //endregion

    //region User Actions
    public void onLanguageSelection(View view) {
        RadioButton selectedRadioButton = (RadioButton)view;
        String tag = selectedRadioButton.getTag().toString();

        // Refresh UI only if current language is different than the previous one
        if (!tag.equalsIgnoreCase(previousLanguage)) {
            refreshUI(tag);
            previousLanguage = tag;
        }
    }
    //endregion

    //region Shared preferences get-set methods
    private void updateLangIsoCodeInPreferences(String languageIsoCode) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("CommonPreferences",this.getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("currentAppLang",languageIsoCode);
        editor.commit();
    }

    private String getLangFromPreferences() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("CommonPreferences",this.getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
        String languageIsoCode = sharedPreferences.getString("currentAppLang", "");
        return  languageIsoCode;
    }
    //endregion
```

How can I optimize memory footprint in stated scenario? Please suggest.

Comment: You probably have a memory leak somewhere,  however you shouldn't offer the ability to select the language in your app. That's not how apps are supposed to work on Android. The whole resource system is geared towards apps respecting the phones language and you shouldn't work against that.

Comment: And by the way: are you actually having memory issues like exceptions that your app is running out of memory? If not than just growing memory usage is no indication of actual memory issues.

Comment: To determine if you have a memory leak, you can force the garbage collector to run from Android Monitor. If the memory footprint goes down after this, you don't have a problem. Android is lazy about cleaning up, it only does it when it has to.

Comment: @DavidWasser thank you for your inputs I will try enabling garbage collector for Android Studio.